# Losing data during joins in Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two tables, with a many to one relationship, and I am using a left join to get all the data from the many table and merge it with the data from the one table.

My first table looks like:

> create table tasks (date text(6),task text(20),completed text(1))

Second table:

> create table completer (data text(6),name text(20))

Keep in mind that date in the completer table is a primary key so only one name is associated with each date.

I can write a query that joins these tables and creates the correct structure:

> select tasks.task,completer.name,tasks.completed from tasks left join completer on tasks.date=completer.date;

The problem with my query is my binary "completed" variable that is either 0, or 1 is always 0 after the join, no matter what value it is in the original table.

Why am I losing the data associated with the completed variable? I've tried using Access's yes/no variable instead, but that has the same problem with losing information during the join.

Thanks

Comment: It seems unlikely that you would be losing data this way.  Have you looked at *all* the rows being returned?  Perhaps the rows with the non-0 value are toward the end of the result set.

Comment: You are right, I just didn't sort.